# Why is redefining a fix sized static array required/works?

Tags: c++

I'm hoping one of you could explain to me why the compiler requires that I redefined a static fixed-length array in the compilation unit despite having already done so in the header. Here's an example:

MyClass.h:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

class MyClass {
private:
    static char myPrecomputeTable[256];
}

#endif
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"

char MyClass::myPrecomputeTable[256];
```

If I remove the redefinition in MyClass.cpp, the linker complains that myPrecomputeTable is undefined. The syntax seems redundant. Could anyone explain to me why the compiler/linker requires the definition?

EDIT:

Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear about what I was confused about. I understand the declaration/definition concept, it's more the defining the size of the array that I find interesting. In both the definition and the declaration, I have to define the size which seems redundant.

EDIT:

I did a bit more digging and it turns out a number of approaches to this topic are compiler friendly.
Compiles:

```
MyClass.h
class MyClass {
    static char myPrecomputeTable[256];
};

MyClass.cpp
char MyClass::myPrecomputeTable[256];
```

Compiles:

```
MyClass.h
class MyClass {
    static char myPrecomputeTable[];
};

MyClass.cpp
char MyClass::myPrecomputeTable[256];
```

Compiles:

```
MyClass.h
class MyClass {
    static char myPrecomputeTable[256];
};

MyClass.cpp
char MyClass::myPrecomputeTable[];
```

Does Not Compile:

```
MyClass.h
class MyClass {
    static char myPrecomputeTable[512];
};

MyClass.cpp
char MyClass::myPrecomputeTable[256];
```

The size has to be defined in either header or class or both, but the compiler is smart enough to stop conflicting sizes.

Comment: The size is actually part of the type. What you have is a variable of type `char [256]`. You apparently don't find it confusing that you need to tell it that `myPrecomputeTable` is a `char` twice, and the size is just an extension of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the header :

```
class MyClass {
private:
    static char myPrecomputeTable[256];
}
```

It is a **declaration**.

And in the .cpp :

```
char MyClass::myPrecomputeTable[256];
```

is a **definition**.

> A **declaration** provides basic attributes of a symbol: its type and its name.
>
> A **definition** provides all of the details of that symbol--if it's a function, what it does; if it's a class, what fields and methods it has; if it's a variable, where that variable is stored.
>
> Often, the compiler only needs to have a declaration for something in order to compile a file into an object file, expecting that the linker can find the definition from another file. If no source file ever defines a symbol, but it is declared, you will get errors at link time complaining about undefined symbols.

A good link to understand the difference between both : http://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html

---

From the standard :

> **3.1 Declarations and definitions [basic.def]**
>
> 1. A declaration may introduce one or more names into a translation unit or redeclare names introduced by previous declarations. If so, the declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of these names. A declaration may also have effects including:
>
>    - a static assertion (Clause 7),
>    - controlling template instantiation (14.7.2),
>    - use of attributes (Clause 7), and
>    - nothing (in the case of an empty-declaration).
> 2. A declaration is a *definition* unless it declares a function without specifying the function’s body, it contains the `extern` specifier or a *linkage-specification* and neither an *initializer* nor a *function-body*, it declares a static data member in a class definition, it is a *class name declaration*, it is an *opaque-enum-declaration*, or it is a *typedef declaration*, a *using-declaration*, a static_assert-declaration, an *attribute-declaration*, an *empty-declaration*, or a *using-directive*.

Answer (score 2):

The first one in the header file is just a *declaration*, telling the compiler that this member exist for all other source files that includes the header file.

The second in the source file is the actual *definition*, and is needed by the linker when linking the whole project together into a single executable.

---

In the case of having to tell the compiler the size twice, that's just how the language is specified to work. There's not much you (or anyone) can do about it.

However, you can use `typedef` to work around it:

```
class MyClass
{
    typedef char PrecomputeTable_t[256];

    static PrecomputeTable_t myPrecomputeTable;
};

...

MyClass::PrecomputeTable_t MyClass::myPrecomputeTable;
```